# How do you monitor the size of the TcpListener backlog?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am using the TcpListener class in C# to open up new tcp connections. I am seeing some performance issues and I want to see if it's due to running over the tcp backlog. Is there some way I can check the current size of the backlog for my process?

Comment: Please specify what kind of performance issues you're seeing.  Frequently, the backlog limit is specified during the `listen` system call and then ignored by the kernel. :-)  A large backlog should not affect your performance.  A short backlog with a lot of incoming connections being ignored would slow down the apparent connect speed once the backlog clears and the client waits to retransmit the initial SYN.  To answer your explicit question, I know of no way to check the current backlog queue size directly.

Comment: did you find an answer.... interested!. as i seem to be running into limitations

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a utility like Wireshark (graphical, but not scriptable from C#, AFAIK). Wireshare uses a library called WinPcap, which does the actual monitoring of the TCP streams on the computer. Decoding of the HTTP headers will need to be done in your application (this is what wireshark/tcpdump/windump should be able to do). You will need to use PInvoke to call the WinPcap DLL. You can find library wrappers by performing a web search for "WinPcap PInvoke".

This question sound very similar to the following:

[Is there any way in .NET to programmatically listen to HTTP traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137407/is-there-any-way-in-net-to-programmatically-listen-to-http-traffic)

Also, [Capturing HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532746/capturing-http-requests) may help